# Javascript: Create Script does not work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, createelement

I'm wiriting on a Chrome Extension. I need too check if a URL is online or not. The URL returns me a variable, so if the var is true, the URL is online.

In case the URL is offline it takes about 2 seconds for the error, so the Extension popup needs 2 seconds to start EVERYtime.

This is my "old" version:

popup.html:

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://example.org/jdcheck.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
```

popup.js:

```
if (variable) { [...] }
```

Well, that worked - after 2 seconds.

Now I had an idea, so I removed the scriptlink in the popup.html.
And that's my new popup.js:

```
background.$(document).ready(function() {


      var jq = document.createElement('script'); jq.type = 'text/javascript';
      jq.src = 'http://127.0.0.1:9666/jdcheck.js';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);

  if(jdownloader){
         [...action]
  }  
});
```

You see, I use jQuery to load the Checkfile.

Now, it throws me an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jdownloader is not defined
```

Well, it looks like the createElement did not work.
I'm 100% sure that the URL gives me the variable I want.

Could you please help me? I don't know how to solve this..

Thank you!
Markus

---

**edit:** I removed the jQuery part, added the keepGoing and the jq.onload:

```
    function keepGoing() {

      console.log("JS should have been loaded");

      if(jdownloader){

        [action]
      }  
    }  

      var jq = document.createElement('script');
      jq.onload = keepGoing();
      jq.src = 'http://127.0.0.1:9666/jdcheck.js';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
```

NOW, the console gives me this:

```
JS should have been loaded popup.js:98
Uncaught ReferenceError: jdownloader is not defined popup.js:100
```

So it seems like the jdownloader var is not passed to the popup.js.
Why..why?! I don't know.

Markus

Comment: You need to wait for the external script to load before you access variables/function from it. Use `jq.onload = function() {// script has been loaded, jdownloader should be there}`

Comment: What is "jdownloader"? It's not defined as var (at least in your snippet)? And what is "background"?

Comment: @mrak: Fairly sure `jdownloader` is created by the script being loaded...

Comment: Exactly, T.J. I will try the onload event, one moment.

Comment: @mrak, the background variable contains the background.js, a command from the Google Chrome Extensions API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you append a script tag to the DOM, the code does not wait for the browser to download and evaluate the script before continuing.

So you have to check back. In Chrome, you can use the `load` event on the `script` element.

```
background.$(document).ready(function() {

    var jq = document.createElement('script'); jq.type = 'text/javascript';
    jq.onload = keepGoing; // Or an anonymous inline function if you prefer
    jq.src = 'http://127.0.0.1:9666/jdcheck.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);

    function keepGoing() {
        if(jdownloader)...
    }  
});
```

("On Chrome" because in older versions of IE, `script` didn't fire the `load` event, it fired `readystatechange`.)

---

Side note: You don't have to supply the `type` attribute if it's `text/javascript`. That is, and always has been, the default.

Comment: Do I call a function with jq.onload? Also I could remove the jQuery part here, though the keepGoing should not load until the js file is loaded. That's right? Cause if I try it, it still gives me the error.

Comment: @wernersbacher: `jq.onload` sets up a function that will get called when the script is loaded.

Comment: I edited the main post, if you got time, just take a look - that would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: @wernersbacher: Please look at the answer again. Not `jq.onload = keepGoing();`, `jq.onload = keepGoing;` (no `()` at the end). You don't want to *call* the function and assign its return value to `jq.onload`, you want to assign the function to `jq.onload` (functions are first-class objects in JavaScript).

Comment: It works now, thank you But it still loads ca. 2 seconds, even if I add jq.async = true; or use the jQuery .ready(). Is this a javascript problem or a Google Chrome problem? I could try to put this in the background.js, which is running all over the time and set an interval for it...still thank you very much!

Comment: Well, I will just set an interval in the background and put a button to the formular to update the status manually. Thank you, sir

Answer (score 0):

The solution may be quite simple, at least for the edited part of your question.
See my jsfiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/6kkC4/1/

`jq.onload = keepGoing();`
vs.

   `jq.onload = keepGoing;`

Calling "onLoad()" will evaluate the function immediately (so not onload).
With `jq.onload = keepGoing;` only a reference to the function is passed
and the function is evaluated onload.

Comment: Yeah, it works now with that, T.J. Crowder told me this also in his comment - but tough thank your for your effort. Markus

Answer (score 0):

Since the "creating a script node" method for doing a JavaScript file Include is asynchronous, we should be using the await and async keywords.

Here is a complete example of how to Include a function called "Context" and then to call it, using Promises (await and async):

```
CallContext(); // Call the async function to do the call

async function CallContext()
    {
    await Include("context.js");
    alert(Context()); // Call Context when Include is done
    } // CallContext

// Wrap the callback of the script element creation in a Promise
async function Include(jsFilePath)
    {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>
        {
        var js = d.createElement("script");
        js.onload = resolve;
        js.src = jsFilePath;
        d.body.appendChild(js);
        });
    } // Include
```

Note that, as yet, there is no modern way to hide the explicit "new Promise" code.